# Из таблицы получить индекс строки, зная элемент который в ней лежит

Tags: html

Как из HTML таблицы получить индекс строки, зная элемент который в ней лежит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/B7j4H/)**

html

```
<table id="test">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span>2</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

var table = document.getElementById('test'),
tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

---

javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) {
    is_el_found = !!tr[i].getElementsByTagName('span').length;
    if (is_el_found) {
        alert(i); # 1
    }
}
```